# RSpec Fails argument match expectation despite no diff

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

How do you place an expectation that the correct `ActiveRecord::Relation` is sent as a keyword argument? I've seen this sort of problem before, and in the past using `hash_including` matcher resolves the issue, but not with `ActiveRecord::Relation`. It is so frustrating because the error shows that there is no **diff** between the expectation and the actual received.

I have a spec that looks something like this:

```rb
describe ProcessAccountsJob, type: :job do
  subject { described_class.new }
  let!(:incomplete) { create(:account, :incomplete_account) }

  it 'calls process batch service' do
    expect(ProcessAccounts).to receive(:batch).with(
      accounts: Account.where(id: incomplete.id)
    )
    subject.perform
  end
end
```

and I get an error that looks like this:

```sh
  1) ProcessAccounts calls process batch service
     Failure/Error: ProcessAccounts.batch(accounts: accounts)

       ProcessAccounts received :batch with unexpected arguments
         expected: ({:accounts=>#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Account id: 14819, account_number: nil...solar: nil, pap: nil, types: [], annualized_usage: nil>]>})
              got: ({:accounts=>#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Account id: 14819, account_number: nil...solar: nil, pap: nil, types: [], annualized_usage: nil>]>})
       Diff:

     # ./app/jobs/process_accounts_job.rb:13:in `perform'
     # ./spec/jobs/process_accounts_job_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
```

As mentioned, trying to use `hash_including` isn't helping. When the spec is changed to:

```rb
describe ProcessAccountsJob, type: :job do
  subject { described_class.new }
  let!(:incomplete) { create(:account, :incomplete_account) }

  it 'calls process batch service' do
    expect(ProcessAccounts).to receive(:batch).with(
      hash_including(accounts: Account.where(id: incomplete.id))
    )
    subject.perform
  end
end
```

the diff becomes:

```
       -["hash_including(:accounts=>#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Account id: 14822, account_number: nil, service_address: \"123 Main St\", created_at: \"2020-07-12 15:50:00\", updated_at: \"2020-07-12 15:50:00\", solar: nil, pap: nil, types: [], annualized_usage: nil>]>)"]
       +[{:accounts=>
       +   #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Account id: 14822, account_number: nil, service_address: "123 Main St", created_at: "2020-07-12 15:50:00", updated_at: "2020-07-12 15:50:00", solar: nil, pap: nil, types: [], annualized_usage: nil>]>}]
```

Comment: Try `hash_including`: `with(hash_including(accounts: Account.where(id: incomplete.id)))`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma Yeah, that isn't helping in this case. See updated output above.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. The problem is that match is checking if both objects are the same, and they're not, unless you pass them somehow from the perform method to the `ProcessAccounts.batch`. How's `ProcessAccountsJob` defined? What `accounts` do you use to call `batch` there?

Comment: Seems that `match_array` is what I needed to do here.

Comment: Randomly ran into this error upgrading from Rspec-rails 5.0.2 -> 5.1.0, using `hash_including` fixed my error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out `match_array` matcher solves the problem in this case; which is pretty misleading because neither the expected nor actual is an array. ‍♂️

```rb
describe ProcessAccountsJob, type: :job do
  subject { described_class.new }
  let!(:incomplete) { create(:account, :incomplete_account) }

  it 'calls process batch service' do
    expect(ProcessAccounts).to receive(:batch).with(
      accounts: match_array(Account.where(id: incomplete.id))
    )
    subject.perform
  end
end
```

Comment: rspec is literally the worst, though it does appear the value of the `accounts` key here was an array